# Why is normalized username in Asp.Net core faster for users searching?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, search

I search 100,000 users search in Asp.Net with UserName and NormalizedUserName. But one thing I noticed is that searching with NormalizedUserName is faster.

```
 await _context.Users.Where(u => u.NormalizedUserName == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 await _context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: In the answer on the marked duplicate: "They are persisted in the database in order be able to create index on them, thus making the lookups by the normalized user name and email sargable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration has an index on `NormalizedUserName`.
See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model)

```
b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex").IsUnique();
```